# Down or up arrow on kendo drop down list causing listbox to show

Tags: kendo-ui, telerik, kendo-dropdown

I'm having a weird issue. My kendo drop down list is revealing the drop down list each time I press the up or down arrow, on all the inputs in my app. Does anyone know what can be causing this? I went to the kendo page that talks about this, but its mostly a reference for the keyboard shortcuts.

I should mention that kitting the down and up arrow DOES change to the next item in the list, but I can't have the dropdown list showing each time.

```
var dataYesNo = [ { text: "Yes", value: 'true' }, { text: "No", value: 'false' } ]; $('#ddlList').kendoDropDownList({ dataSource: dataYesNo, dataValueField: 'value', dataTextField: 'text', optionLabel: 'select a value...' });
```

Comment: Can you post your declaration of the kendo-dropdown within your app? This will make it easier to diagnose what's wrong.

Comment: var dataYesNo = [
    { text: "Yes", value: 'true' },
    { text: "No", value: 'false' }
    ];

    $('#ddlList').kendoDropDownList({
        dataSource: dataYesNo,
        dataValueField: 'value',
        dataTextField: 'text',
        optionLabel: 'select a value...'
    });

Comment: Have you used any javascript code? Please add you code completely?

Answer (score 0):

OK, I figured it out. I stumbled onto this ...

http://www.telerik.com/forums/conflict-w-bootstrap-js-dropdownlist

I had to upgrade my bootstrap version to 3.3.5 and works like a charm. Regardless, thanks for the assistance.